# Disable scroll-top on back button with SPA functionality

Tags: javascript, scroll, xmlhttprequest, single-page-application

I'm currently working on [this project](https://github.com/moonfacedesign/tabs) which adds SPA functionality to SSG sites. I've ran into a issue with the use of `window.scrollTo(0, 0)`

At the moment on back button input (pushstate) the SPA will go to the top by default. I only want the `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` to work on href and **not** pushstate since this creates a glitching effect that is distracting.

Here is the repo with an example of SPA functionality with a site. There are instructions for quick start in readMe.
https://github.com/moonfacedesign/atmos/tree/stack-001

Site
https://mf-stackpost-001.onrender.com

Can I use `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` somewhere else so it will not work on back button or is there another method I need to look into?

Cheers.

Comment: It will be easier for us to help you if you provide a [mre] here.

Comment: I have updated the post. Let me know if you need anything else.